# Is this explanation of coronavirus accurate?

Tags: immune-system, virus, covid-19

I have seen the following post popping up on Facebook recently:

> Feeling confused as to why Coronavirus is a bigger deal than Seasonal
>   flu?  Here it is in a nutshell.   I hope this helps.  Feel free to
>   share this to others who don’t understand...
>
> It has to do with RNA sequencing....  I.e. genetics.
>
> Seasonal flu is an “all human virus”.  The DNA/RNA chains that make up
>   the virus are recognized by the human immune system.  This means that
>   your body has some immunity to it before it comes around each year... 
>   you get immunity two ways...through exposure to a virus, or by getting
>   a flu shot.
>
> Novel viruses can come from animals....  the WHO tracks novel viruses
>   in animals, (sometimes for years watching for mutations). Usually
>   these viruses only transfer from animal to animal (pigs in the case of
>   H1N1) (birds in the case of the Spanish flu).  But once, one of these
>   animal viruses mutates, and starts to transfer from animals to
>   humans... then it’s a problem,  Why? Because we have no natural or
>   acquired immunity.. the RNA sequencing of the genes inside the virus
>   isn’t human, and the human immune system doesn’t recognize it so, we
>   can’t fight it off.
>
> Now.... sometimes, the mutation only allows transfer from animal to
>   human, for years it’s only transmission is  from an infected animal to
>   a human before  it finally mutates so that it can now transfer human
>   to human... once that happens..we have a new contagion phase.  And
>   depending on the fashion of this new mutation, thats what decides how
>   contagious, or how deadly it’s gonna be..
>
> H1N1 was deadly....but it did not mutate in a way that was as deadly
>   as the Spanish flu.    It’s RNA was slower to mutate and it attacked
>   its host differently, too.
>
> Fast forward.
>
> Now, here comes this Coronavirus... it existed in animals only, for
>   nobody knows how long...but one day, at an animal market, in Wuhan
>   China, in December 2019, it mutated and made the jump from animal to
>   people.  At first, only animals could give it to a person... But here
>   is the scary part.... in just TWO WEEKS it mutated again and gained
>   the ability to jump from human to human.   Scientists call this quick
>   ability, “slippery”
>
> This Coronavirus, not being in any form a “human” virus (whereas we
>   would all have some natural or acquired immunity). Took off like a
>   rocket.  And this was because, Humans have no known immunity...doctors
>   have no known medicines for it.
>
> And it just so happens that this particular mutated animal virus,
>   changed itself in such a way the way that it causes great damage to
>   human lungs..
>
> That’s why Coronavirus is different from seasonal flu, or H1N1 or any
>   other type of influenza....  this one is slippery AF.   And it’s a
>   lung eater...And, it’s already mutated AGAIN, so that we now have two
>   strains to deal with, strain s, and strain L....which makes it twice
>   as hard to develop a vaccine.
>
> We really have no tools in our shed, with this.  History has shown
>   that fast and immediate closings of public places has helped in the
>   past pandemics.  Philadelphia and Baltimore were reluctant to close
>   events in 1918 and they were the hardest hit in the US during the
>   Spanish Flu.
>
> Factoid:  Henry VIII stayed in his room and allowed no one near him,
>   till the Sweating Sickness that plagued his time had
>   passed...(honestly...I understand him so much better now). Just like
>   us, he had no tools in his shed, except social isolation...
>
> And let me end by saying....right now it’s hitting older folks
>   harder... but this genome is so slippery...if it mutates again (and it
>   will). Who is to say, what it will do next.
>
> Be smart folks...  acting like you’re unafraid is so not sexy right
>   now.
>
> #flattenthecurve.  Stay home folks...  and share this to those that just are not catching on.

Most of this I have no particular dispute with, but the claim

> But once, one of these
>   animal viruses mutates, and starts to transfer from animals to
>   humans... then it’s a problem,  Why? Because we have no natural or
>   acquired immunity.. the RNA sequencing of the genes inside the virus
>   isn’t human, and the human immune system doesn’t recognize it so, we
>   can’t fight it off.

sounds like saying that we can only *gain* an immunity to a virus that has human RNA in it. It seems to me more likely that we merely don't have any *existing* immunity to it because it is brand new to the human immune system; now that we've seen it, we'll gain immunity to it, and who cares what RNA is inside it? <s>(And again, my gut says that it is the human RNA that actually gives it access to infect humans and thus become prevalent enough in the body to become a valid target for the immune system).</s> But I'm no virologist, and I'm curious what the reality is.

Comment: Sounds like something for skeptics